# Parameterized version like Spring Boot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, parameterized

I want to parameterize Maven version as a variable like Spring Boot.

Every submodule use version as `<version>${revision}</version>`.

@see git@github.com:iPhotoner/parameterized-version-demo.git

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>demo-ri</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo-parent</artifactId>
        <version>parameterized.version</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <demo.version>parameterized.version</demo.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo-api</artifactId>
            <version>${demo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>maven-public</name>
            <url>http://192.168.1.1:8089/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: take a deep look into https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: yes,this is the answer,some problem with flatten-maven-plugin,thank you for guidance.

Comment: Can you tell which problems you have with flatten-maven-plugin? Do we need to improve the . docs?

Answer (score 0):

thanks,@khmarbaise,
i give up using maven-ci-friendly at present,maybe ${revision} something wrong with ${revision} under spring boot,and some version i can not hold it;

first,i created a module extends parent:
[Not Covered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk2yF.png)

second:flatten plugin occurs on eclipse 4.7.3a java standard version;
[Can Not Load Flatten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frhn1.png)

three:use flatten plugin inherited:true or false, and starter-* open,
project works fine,junit five and restdoc can extend from starter module,
if do not use flatten,also works fine:

```html
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0</version>
         <!-- <inherited>true or false</inherited> -->
         <configuration>
           <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>flatten</id>
              <phase>process-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>flatten</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
           <execution>
              <id>flatten.clean</id>
              <phase>clean</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
```

[Extend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAnhA.png)

step four:if i execute mvn clean deploy upload jar to nexus,and close 
starter module,errors on project cif-dependency,this project 
has no relation with starter module(just extends from it),
and junit five/restdocs can not be extends from starter module,
[Not Extend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecm4I.png)